# using split for appending to multiple lists

Tags: python

Is it possible to combine the two statements inside 'for' loop.

```
num_pro=raw_input("ENTER THE NUMBER OF PRODUCTIONS: ")

right=[];left=[];

for i in range(int(num_pro)):
   l,r=raw_input("ENTER PRODUCTION"+str(i+1)+" : ").split('->')
   right.append(r);left.append(l)
```

sample input: E->abc

Comment: Sorry, what is your question, exactly?

Comment: split is giving two values. i want to append them to lists directly instead of 1st storing in variables and then appending them to lists. how to do that?
something like
    `right.append(r);left.append(l)=raw_input("ENTER PRODUCTION"+str(i+1)+" : ").split('->')`

Comment: Why is `r` on the left and `l` on the right?

Comment: just used two variables. didn't got in mind that English is wrong.

Comment: why there is a problem in asking this question i can't understand.

we use one-line swapping code
`*b = (*a + *b) - (*a = *b)` instead of
`temp = x;
   x    = y;
   y    = temp;`
though the later is easy to understand.
then why it's not right in asking to minimize the code here(though one-line).

Comment: How about: `map(list.append, (left, right), raw_input("ENTER PRODUCTION"+str(i+1)+" : ").split('->'))` It should work, though I'm not sure it's a good idea to pack so much stuff into a single line.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks man. **u r a genius.** that's the exact thing i'm talking about.
@ others, may be it's complex. but something new to learn is always nice.

Answer (score 2):

Append tuples to *one* list, then split out the lists using `zip()`:

```
entries = []

for i in range(int(num_pro)):
    entries.append(raw_input("ENTER PRODUCTION"+str(i+1)+" : ").split('->'))

left, right = zip(*entries)
```

`zip(*iterable)` transposes the nested list; columns become rows. Because you have two 'columns' (pairs of values), you end up with two rows instead.

Comment: i'd like to decrease the no. of lines in code. and it's giving me same no. of lines.

Comment: @RatDon: This is Python; don't try to reduce lines needlessly. First and foremost *keep it readable*.

Comment: Reducing lines of Python code usually complicates it and can slow it down in other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Not without making it more complex. Each method needs to be called individually, and the only way to do that is either explicitly, as you have done, or in a loop.

If you are willing to store the whole production (which isn't necessarily a bad idea, since it keeps both sides synchronized) then just append the split result instead.

```
productions = []

for ...
  productions.append(....split('->'))
```

Comment: for my rest of the program i need to keep them in separate lists.
the input may be like
E->a*b
E->a+b
E->a/b
and i want to store both sides with repetition and later retrieve the positions.